# fluentd/kafka : SASL authentication requires that SSL is configured

Tags: security, networking, apache-kafka, fluentd, sasl

I am planning to send logs to our cooperate elastic search cluster.

I am using td-agent to forward logs to Kafka endpoints which are connected to cooperate elastic search cluster. I have installed the fluent-plugin-kafka plugin with td-agent to send logs to Kafka endpoints which are connected to cooperate elastic search cluster

Plugin Url : https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka

LOGS SENDING PATHS AS BELOW:

```
logs --> td-agent+fluent-plugin-kafka --> kafka cluster --> elasticsearch --> kibana
```

The issue is, Kafka endpoints are configured in a way to support SASL AUTHENTICATION without supporting SSL, Since logs are only routed with cooperate network, I guess no need to have SSL support.

I am getting bellow error :

```
  2019-04-30 17:46:39 +0900 [error]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.3.3/bin/fluentd:8:in `<top (required)>'
  2019-04-30 17:46:39 +0900 [error]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `load'
  2019-04-30 17:46:39 +0900 [error]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `<main>'
2019-04-30 17:46:39 +0900 [error]: #0 unexpected error error_class=ArgumentError error="SASL authentication requires that SSL is configured"
  2019-04-30 17:46:39 +0900 [error]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-04-30 17:46:39 +0900 [info]: Worker 0 finished unexpectedly with status 1
^C
```

My td-agent configs are :

```
#
<source>
  @type dummy
  dummy {"hello":"world"}
  tag test
</source>

<match test>
  @type kafka2
  brokers               stg-ageapdsk101.stg.hnd2.bdd.local:9002,stg-ageapdsk102.stg.hnd2.bdd.local:9002,stg-ageapdsk103.stg.hnd2.bdd.local:9002
  principal             'appuser@STGKAFKA100.GEAP.XXX.COM'
  keytab                'appuser.keytab'
  client_id             'kafka'
  sasl_over_ssl         false
  get_kafka_client_log  true
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
  topic_key             'stg_esd_app_elk_1'
  get_kafka_client_log  true

  <buffer topic>
    flush_interval 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In an environment of cloudera 6.3 with Kerberos authentication (GSSAPI), fluentd v1.9.2 plugin fluent-plugin-kafkav0.13.0, out_kafka2 did not work. As an alternative module in the same plugin, I tried rdkafka2 and it works now.

Details;

principal and keytab same as kafka2

parameters specific to rdkafka2
service_name 'kafka'

you can check [the code](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/out_rdkafka2.rb), as it fills all the necessary parameters for GSSAPI, SASL_PAINTEXT scenario.

```
if @principal
sasl = true
config[:"sasl.mechanisms"] = "GSSAPI"
config[:"sasl.kerberos.principal"] = @principal
config[:"sasl.kerberos.service.name"] = @service_name if @service_name
config[:"sasl.kerberos.keytab"] = @keytab if @keytab
end

  if ssl && sasl
    security_protocol = "SASL_SSL"
  elsif ssl && !sasl
    security_protocol = "SSL"
  elsif !ssl && sasl
    security_protocol = "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  else
    security_protocol = "PLAINTEXT"
  end
  config[:"security.protocol"] = security_protocol
```

Added to this, do not forget to add environment variable -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/jaas.conf
for details of jaas conf this [link](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.1.0/kafka-securing/topics/kafka-secure-kerberos-enable.html).

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me
use `sasl_over_ssl: false`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Instead of sasl_over_ssl false, use ssl_ca_cert with no value
e.g 
client_id 'kafka'
ssl_ca_cert
keytab 'appuser.keytab

THANKS